# Conda command not found even after PATH defined

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda with Mac installer (and also tried .sh installer with bash). The installation created the PATH in `.bash_profile` file automatically like the following:

```
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
# added by Anaconda2 2.5.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/MyUserName/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

I restarted Terminal and even the computer. When I type `conda ....` in the command line, I still receive the `-bash: conda: command not found` error. Am I doing/missing sth. wrong? I am using OS X Yosemite. Thanks

Comment: sorry.. a small typo. "conda" and problem still ongoing.

Comment: Has `.bash_profile` been sourced since the installation? If you look at the path with `echo $PATH`, is the anaconda directory in there?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the reply. I checked usr/lib/bin Conda Unix Executable file was not in the folder. I added manually. Now works well. But it is strange that Conda is not there by default after the installation. Anyways.. Can you re-write as reply, so I give the credit. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this? Can you do:
`echo $PATH`
.. and show what is output?

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same problem. I couldn't find a viable solution so I removed anaconda completely from my system using :

```
sudo rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

Then downloaded anaconda again and installed it. This is a workaround solution but it worked for me.